# Почему не работает sticky на мобильных устройствах? | Table

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, табличная-верстка, sticky

У меня используются такие стили, чтобы сделать th в качестве sticky для многих устройств. Но работает только на ПК.

```css
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <table id="summary-city" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-thead-sticky">
    <thead class="report-thead" id="header">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center !important; vertical-align: middle !important; width: 12.5%;">Шапка 1</th>
        <th style="text-align: center !important; vertical-align: middle !important; width: 12.5%;">Шапка 2</th>
        <th style="text-align: center !important; vertical-align: middle !important; width: 12.5%;">Шапка 3</th>
        <!--- ... --->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Вся проблема с том, что на ПК все отлично. Sticky работает для th, а вот на мобильных устройствах не работает.
Попытался сделать так:

CSS:

```css
@media (max-width: 1300px) {
    th {
        background: white;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
}
```

Но это безрезультатно...

Comment: `sticky` довольно "свежее" значение... Может не все мобильные браузеры с ним еще работают не так как ПК-браузеры

Comment: @ksa Как можно добиться того, чтобы на телефоне тоже работало?

Comment: Как вариант - отслеживать позицию скрола... Делать элемент `position: fixed;` для достижения эффекта "прилипания" и убирать такое когда нужно опять "двигаться".

Comment: Но в таком случае может слететь позиция. Я имею ввиду, что thead съедет вообще. А tbody изменит размеры.

Comment: Разумеется такое сделать не совсем просто... Но можно не трогать сам элемент, просто сделать его прозрачным например... А зрителю показать его клон, который по внешнему виду ничем не отличается от оригинала. ;)

Comment: Не подскажешь, как его тогда в том же самом положении оставить, если создавать копию? Я в JS не сильно селен, поэтому могу задать такие глупые вопросы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148059/discussion-between-dr-fap-and-ksa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, нашел проблему. Связана с тем, что для определенных устройств стоит этот стиль:

```css
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .main {
        overflow-y: hidden
    }
}
```

Это стояло в глобальных стилях.